# Getting normals in webgl for projected surface

Tags: webgl, projection

I have vertices of some surfaces that I draw on the canvas using drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,...). I need to draw these surfaces for a particular camera viewpoint and hence all 3d points are projected into 2d and I download the final image using toDataUrl. Here is the downloaded image:

[image]

I used gl.readPixels later to retrieve the data for everypixel.

For all the edge vertices, I have the information for the normals. Just like how I got the color for every pixel in the 2d images, I want to get the normals at every pixel for 2d image. Since I only have the normals at the edge vertices, I decided to render the normals the same way I rendered the above image and decided to use gl.readpixels. This is not working. Here is the relevant code:

This is the function from which the drawOverlayTriangeNormals is called. The drawOverlayTriangles function (not visible in this post) was used to produce the image shown above.

```
    //Saving BIM
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.vertexAttrib1f(shaderProgram.aIsDepth, 0.0);
    drawOverlayTriangles();
    saveBlob('element');

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.vertexAttrib1f(shaderProgram.aIsDepth, 0.0);
    drawOverlayTrianglesNormals();
    saveBlob('element');

    var pixels = new Uint8Array(glCanvas.width*glCanvas.height*4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, glCanvas.width, glCanvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,pixels);
    pixels = new Float32Array(pixels.buffer);   
}
```

This is the drawOverlayTrianglesNormals function:

```
function drawOverlayTrianglesNormals()
{
if (overlay.numElements <= 0)
    return;

//Creating the matrix for normal transform
var normal_matrix = mat4.create();
var u_Normal_Matrix = mat4.create();
mat4.invert(normal_matrix,pMVMatrix);
mat4.transpose(u_Normal_Matrix,normal_matrix);  

gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);   

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aVertexPosition);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aVertexColor);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aNormal);
gl.vertexAttrib1f(shaderProgram.aIsNormal, 1.0);

//Matrix upload
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uMVMatrix, false, pMVMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uPMatrix, false, perspM);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uNMatrix, false, u_Normal_Matrix);

//Create normals buffer
normals_buffer = gl.createBuffer();

for (var i = 0; i < overlay.numElements; i++) {
    // Upload overlay vertices                      
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, overlayVertices[i]);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Upload overlay colors
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, overlayTriangleColors[i]);       
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.aVertexColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    var normal_vertex = [];

    //Upload Normals
        var normals_element = overlay.elementNormals[i];
        for( var j=0; j< overlay.elementNumVertices[i]; j++)
    {   
        var x = normals_element[3*j+0];
        var y = normals_element[3*j+1];
        var z = normals_element[3*j+2];
        var length = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);

        normal_vertex[3*j+0] = x/length;
        normal_vertex[3*j+1] = y/length;
        normal_vertex[3*j+2] = z/length;
    }
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normals_buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normal_vertex),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.aNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);    

    // Draw overlay
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, overlay.elementNumVertices[i]);
}

gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aVertexPosition);
gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.aVertexColor);
gl.vertexAttrib1f(shaderProgram.aisdepth, 0.0);
}
```

Below is the relevant vertex shader code:

```
 void main(void) {
        gl_PointSize = aPointSize;
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        position_1 = gl_Position;
        vColor = aVertexColor;
        vIsDepth = aIsDepth;
        vIsNormal = aIsNormal;
        vHasTexture = aHasTexture;
        normals = uNMatrix*vec4(aNormal,1.0);
        if (aHasTexture > 0.5)
            vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

    }
```

Fragment shader:

```
 if (vIsNormal > 0.5)
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(normals.xyz*0.5+0.5,1);

        }
    }
```

Right now my output is the same image in grayscale. I am not sure what is going wrong. I felt this method makes sense but seems a little round about.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you wanted to do, but if you want to have a pixel's normal in your fragment shader, you can just "give" it to it by your vertex shader with a `varying` variable.

Comment: I'm not really understanding either. You can either call 'canvas.toDataURL` or `gl.readPixels` to get the data out of the canvas. As for rendering the normals, yea, just pass them through to the fragment shader from the vertex shader and then renderer with them as in `gl_FragCoord = vec4(normal * 0.5 + 0.5, 1);`

Comment: I just want the normals of all the rendered points and not just the vertices. Right now the colors are done manually by checking the normal and using it in gl_FragColor. If I want the normals for every pixel, should I render a separate image with just normal values and use readPixels?

Comment: I have edited my post after trying out what was mentioned in the comments above. I have also included some relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it seems like you just want to be able to access the normals for calculating lighting effects, so let me try to answer that.

DO NOT use gl.readPixels()!  This is primarily for click interactions and stuff, or modifying small numbers of pixels.  Using this must be extremely inefficient, since you have to draw the pixels, then read them, then redraw them after calculating their appropriate lighting.  The wonderful thing about WebGL is that it allows you to do all this from the beginning: the fragment shader will interpolate the information it's given to smoothly draw effects between two adjacent vertices.

Most of lighting depends comparing the surface normal to the direction of the light (as you seem to understand, judging by one of your comments).  See [Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading).

Now, you mentioned that you want the normals of all the rendered points, not just at the vertices.  BUT the vertices' normals will be identical to the normals at every point on the surface, so you don't even need anything more than the vertices' normals.  This is because all WebGL knows how to draw is triangles (I believe), which are flat, or planar, surfaces.  And since every point on a plane has the same normal as any other point, you only really need one normal to know all of the normals!

Since it looks like all you're trying to draw are cylinders and rectangular prisms, it ought to be simple to specify the normals the objects you create.  The normals for the rectangular prisms are trivial, but so are those of the cylinder: the normals are parallel to the line going from the axis of the cylinder to the surface.

And since WebGL's fragment shader interpolates any `varying` variables you pass it between adjacent vertices, you can tell it to interpolate these normals smoothly across vertices, to achieve the smooth lighting seen in the Phong shadin page! :D